# swift reload data UICollectionView

Tags: swift

```
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionview.delegate = self
    collectionview.dataSource = self
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.refreshData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    fetchPosts()
    collectionview.addSubview(refreshControl)

}

@objc func refreshData() {
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()

}
```

I have a UITabBar with some ViewController. In a ViewController i have a UICollectionView where there are images of users. Every users can load an image and this image is seen in the controller with UICollectionView. once the photo is loaded, in the UICollectionView it does not appear because the data must be refreshed. In the function RefreshData what should I do to refresh the UICollectionView?

Comment: There are several answers now providing the basics of how to refresh the UICollectionView.  You say they do not work but provide no more details.  So the problem lies outside the code you have provided.  If you don't go into more details your not going to get anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the collection view by using:

```
@objc func refreshData() {
    collectionview.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

You can also consider to use a simple image caching library, as [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) for example, to avoid full collection view refresh for this.

Comment: So can you share more of your code? Mainly the cellForItem method, and the way you download images

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to call `reloadData()` for `collectionView`, i.e.

```
@objc func refreshData() 
{
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

You must have an `IBOutlet` for `collectionView` in your `ViewController`.

Comment: Tell the issue that you are facing? Are you updating your `collectionView` dataSource?

Comment: yes, the problem is that when i refresh the collection view, it does not refresh

Comment: Your `dataSource` from which you are loading data into the `collectionView` might not be updated in that case.

Comment: what can I do? please

Comment: If that is the case then why are you using `refreshControl`? Add more code to of what actually you are doing,

Comment: that is, how should I do without refresh control?

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc func refreshData() 
{
    self.arr.removeAll()
    fetchPosts()
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

API Call

```
func fetchPosts() {
    self.arr.removeAll()
    //API call code..
    //after success response you need to reload collectionView
}
```

you need to call api when you want to refresh so that you will get updated data.and more thing in API response you also need to `self.collectionView.reloadData()` when you get successfull response.

Comment: the new elements appear but the previous ones are doubled

Comment: @azimut345 you need to remove your old array when you call API

Comment: @azimut345 please see updated answer and let me know.

Comment: @azimut345 may you please show your code ? and update your question as you did.

Comment: other ideas? Because I always have the same problem

Comment: @azimut345 this is best idea please refer your code and see any small mistake is there or not..otherwise my coding will work..i have tested my coding in my project.